# Downloading an old version of R on mac

Tags: r

Does anyone have an updated way of downloading an old version of R on Mac? This used to be the old link: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/old but it no longer works.

I've been searching for a few days and have still not found a way to download a previous version (specifically 4.2) for Mac OS. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/base

Versions available:
R-4.0.0.pkg
R-4.0.1.pkg
R-4.0.2.pkg
R-4.0.3.pkg
R-4.0.4.pkg
R-4.0.5.pkg
R-4.1.0.pkg
R-4.1.1.pkg
R-4.1.2.pkg
R-4.1.3.pkg
R-4.2.0.pkg
R-4.2.1.pkg
R-4.2.2.pkg
R-4.2.3.pkg

Comment: Any idea how you actually use the base versions though? As in, without the installer?

Comment: the .pkg is the installer, use it to install 4.2.0. And then you can use this free utility to switch between versions https://rud.is/rswitch/